# How can i save object with list using pickle in python?

Tags: python, list, class, object, pickle

I am trying to save object with list of another class objects.

```
    def loadBot(self, name):

       BotFile = open('../Bots/' + name, 'rb+')

       self.CurrentBot = pickle.load(BotFile)

       BotFile.close() # Closes file

    def saveBot(self, bot):

       BotFile = open('../Bots/' + bot.Name, 'wb+') 

       BotFile.truncate() # Clear File
       pickle.dump(bot, BotFile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) 

       BotFile.close() # Close file
```

These are functions i am using to load object and save. In object Bot i have list of objects 'Blueprint' and function add blueprint.

```
    class ChatBot:

       Name = 'DefaultName'
       Token = 'DefaultToken'
       bot_blueprints = []

       def __init__(self, Name, Token):
         self.Name = Name
         self.Token = Token

      def addBlueprint(self):
        self.bot_blueprints.append(Blueprint(len(self.bot_blueprints)))
```

I am adding new element and checking list size before saving and after

```
app.loadBot('A')
print(len(app.CurrentBot.bot_blueprints))
app.CurrentBot.addBlueprint()
app.saveBot(app.CurrentBot)
print(len(app.CurrentBot.bot_blueprints))
```

It start from 0, after adding bp becomes 1. After this i am closing app, start it second time and my code should write 1 after opening and 2 after adding but it's still 0 and 1. File size growing but pickle can't rightly load my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you've written the code `bot_blueprints` is a class level variable, not an instance level one.  thus there is only one in the whole program, rather than one for each `ChatBot`

I'd rearrange the class to be more like:

```
class ChatBot:
   def __init__(self, name, token):
     self.name = name
     self.token = token
     self.bot_blueprints = []

  def addBlueprint(self):
    self.bot_blueprints.append(Blueprint(len(self.bot_blueprints)))
```

Comment: no probs, glad it helped! if this solves your problem you can mark this answer as "Accepted"